# PHP Pear how to enable debug level?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, smarty, pear

I'm trying to migrate a website from 1 linux (php4) PC to another 1 linux PC (php5).

The website is made of Apache+PHP+Smarty+MYSQL.

Now I'm getting this error "DB_DataObject Error: Connect failed, turn on debugging to 5 see why "

I have basic knowledge on PHP, can anyone help me how I can debug the problem? Thanks.

Comment: So, does both boxes installed with compatible pear packages?

Comment: ajreal> it seems the website was copied from a paid webhost, and I don't have access to it currently, so I can't really compare it. I managed to get apache+php+smarty working so far, but that DB_DataObject problem from PEAR still persists...

Answer (score 2):

DB_Dataobject has its own debugging-stuff. PEAR::setErrorHandling is a red herring.

Instead, insert

```
DB_DataObject::debugLevel(5);
```

somewhere and reload.

For instance:

```
require_once 'DB/DataObject.php';
DB_DataObject::debugLevel(5);
```